# Create well structured pandas dataframe using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda DataFreme data from 2018 to 2020. I want to structure these data as follows.

```
Month | 2018 | 2019
Jan     115    73
Feb     112    63
....
```

up to December.

How can I solve this issue using panda data frame syntax?

```
Date
2018-01-01    115.0
2018-02-01    112.0
2018-03-01    104.5
2018-04-01     91.1
2018-05-01     85.5
2018-06-01     76.5
2018-07-01     86.5
2018-08-01     77.9
2018-09-01     65.0
2018-10-01     71.0
2018-11-01     76.0
2018-12-01     72.5
2019-01-01     73.0
2019-02-01     63.0
2019-03-01     63.0
2019-04-01     61.0
2019-05-01     58.3
2019-06-01     59.0
2019-07-01     67.0
2019-08-01     64.0
2019-09-01     59.9
2019-10-01     70.4
2019-11-01     78.9
2019-12-01     75.0
2020-01-01     73.9
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more like pivot but with `crosstab`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df.index.strftime('%b'),df.index.year,df.values,aggfunc='sum')
Out[87]: 
col_0   2018  2019  2020
row_0                   
Apr     91.1  61.0   NaN
Aug     77.9  64.0   NaN
Dec     72.5  75.0   NaN
Feb    112.0  63.0   NaN
Jan    115.0  73.0  73.9
Jul     86.5  67.0   NaN
Jun     76.5  59.0   NaN
Mar    104.5  63.0   NaN
May     85.5  58.3   NaN
Nov     76.0  78.9   NaN
Oct     71.0  70.4   NaN
Sep     65.0  59.9   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` and `unstack`:

```
(s.groupby([s.index.month, s.index.year]).first().unstack()
  .rename_axis(columns='Year',index='Month')
)
```

Output:

```
Year    2018  2019  2020
Month                   
1      115.0  73.0  73.9
2      112.0  63.0   NaN
3      104.5  63.0   NaN
4       91.1  61.0   NaN
5       85.5  58.3   NaN
6       76.5  59.0   NaN
7       86.5  67.0   NaN
8       77.9  64.0   NaN
9       65.0  59.9   NaN
10      71.0  70.4   NaN
11      76.0  78.9   NaN
12      72.5  75.0   NaN
```